# Copy site root libraries and sub libraries with all permission using Get-PnPSiteTemplate

Tags: powershell, pnp

Our SharePoint sites have yearly structure like 2024->subfolders. When I use below PowerShell code to copy existing site template to new site then I am getting only root folders created. Each root folders have six subfolders. Any help on how I can duplicate exact same existing site configuration to new site using PowerShell.

```
$ExistingSiteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive/"
$SiteTemplateFile = "\Template.xml"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $ExistingSiteUrl 
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out $SiteTemplateFile -force

#Create New Site
$newurl = New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Test Root Archive" -Alias "Archive1"
$TargetSiteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Archive1"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TargetSiteUrl 
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $SiteTemplateFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SharePoint CSOM, based on this, here is a snippet.
See: [Copy library to different site collection with pnp](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276955/copy-library-to-different-site-collection-with-pnp)

```
Function Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $SourceFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $TargetFolder
    )
    Try {
        # Get all Files from the source folder
        $SourceFilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files
        $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceFilesColl)
        $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

        # Iterate through each file and copy
        Foreach ($SourceFile in $SourceFilesColl) {
            # Get the source file
            $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($SourceFolder.Context, $SourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl)

            # Copy File to the Target location
            $TargetFileURL = $TargetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $SourceFile.Name
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::SaveBinaryDirect($TargetFolder.Context, $TargetFileURL, $FileInfo.Stream, $True)

            # Copy Metadata field values
            $SourceListItem = $SourceFile.ListItemAllFields
            $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SourceListItem)
            $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

            # Get the new file created
            $TargetFile = $TargetFolder.Context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFileURL)
            $TargetListItem = $TargetFile.ListItemAllFields

            # Set Metadata values from the source
            $Author = $TargetFolder.Context.web.EnsureUser($SourceListItem["Author"].Email)
            $TargetListItem["Author"] = $Author
            $Editor = $TargetFolder.Context.web.EnsureUser($SourceListItem["Editor"].Email)
            $TargetListItem["Editor"] = $Editor
            $TargetListItem["Created"] = $SourceListItem["Created"]
            $TargetListItem["Modified"] = $SourceListItem["Modified"]
            $TargetListItem.Update()
            $TargetFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-host -f Green "Copied File '$($SourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl)' to '$TargetFileURL'"
        }

        # Process Sub Folders
        $SubFolders = $SourceFolder.Folders
        $SourceFolder.Context.Load($SubFolders)
        $SourceFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Foreach ($SubFolder in $SubFolders) {
            If ($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms") {
                # Prepare Target Folder
                $TargetFolderURL = $SubFolder.ServerRelativeUrl -replace $SourceLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, $TargetLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                Try {
                    $Folder = $TargetFolder.Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($TargetFolderURL)
                    $TargetFolder.Context.load($Folder)
                    $TargetFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
                }
                catch {
                    # Create Folder
                    if (!$Folder.Exists) {
                        $TargetFolderURL
                        $Folder = $TargetFolder.Context.web.Folders.Add($TargetFolderURL)
                        $TargetFolder.Context.Load($Folder)
                        $TargetFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
                        Write-host "Folder Added:" $SubFolder.Name -f Yellow
                    }
                }
                # Call the function recursively
                Copy-AllFilesWithMetadata -SourceFolder $SubFolder -TargetFolder $Folder
            }
        }
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Copying File!"
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: our requirement is to copy the exact folder structure with permissions to new site. We don't want to copy or move site content/files. Except files we want everything to be copied to new site.